# is there a way in python to integrate objects of inner class with objects of outer class?

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I am new to Object oriented programming in python. I have tried to attempt a small piece of code to understand how the classes work especially the nested classes. Please see to below piece of code. I need to assign a few arguments for the parameters in Laptop class. after that the show method in Students class has to invoke attributes from Laptop instance and then pop the message as per the `show()` method. For example if I create `lap1 = Laptop("HP","i5","8GB")` then the show method should display "Gowtham has HP Laptop". I am not able to figure what is going wrong.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,rollno):
        self.name = name
        self.rollno = rollno
        self.lap = self.Laptop()
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} has roll number {self.rollno}"
    
    def show(self):
            print(self.name + " has " + self.lap.brand + " laptop")
    
    class Laptop:
        def __init__(self,brand,cpu,ram):
            self.brand = brand
            self.cpu = cpu
            self.ram = ram
            
        def display(self):
            print(self.brand,self.cpu,self.ram)
        
s1 = Student("Gowtham",55)
print(s1)
lap1 = Laptop("HP","i5","8GB")
s1.show()
```

After attempting this code, i am getting an error, which displays as TypeError:

```
__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'brand', 'cpu', and 'ram'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you're confused on what is the point of a nested class and how it relates to it's parent class.

Just cause you nest a class definition inside another doesn't mean that the parent class instantly creates/has access to the nested class.

Nesting classes is really only used to help organize classes that are similar. Even than it would most likely be better to just have separate unnested classes inside one module. For instance you could argue this is a good reason to nest a class cause they are similar.

```
class Containers:
    class Box:
        pass

    class Cup:
        pass

    class Bowl:
        pass
```

Notice that though they share a similarity they don't rely on each for anything. They are just nested to help with organization. But it would probably be better to just unnest those classes and put them in a file called `containers.py`

So back to you situation. It would be better to unnest the class. Instantiate a `Laptop` object. Then to fix you're error instantiate a `Student` object and pass in the newly created `Laptop` object you created. So like this.

```
laptop = Laptop(brand, cpu, ram)
student = Student(name, rollno, laptop)
```

Then inside the `Student` `__init__` change it from `self.laptop = self.Laptop()` to `self.laptop = laptop`

It should work for you now.

Comment: Thanks Mate, with your tip my code worked. But i do still want to know whether the output that i am looking for will n't be possible through nested classes ? Just a curiosity.. :)

Comment: Yes it is possible with a nested class but not with the current way you're working with it. You have two ways of doing it. The same way i posted above but when you instantiate the `Laptop` it would be `laptop = Student.Laptop(brand, cpu, ram)`. Or you can pass all laptop parameter into `Student` like `Student(name, rollno, brand, cpu, ram)` and then inside of `__init__` of `Student` you would just change `self.laptop = self.Laptop()` to `self.laptop = Student.Laptop(brand, cpu, ram)` since now those parameters have been passed into the `__init__` of `Student`.

Comment: Thank you very much mate, I have understood now what is the mistake that i have committed with the nested classes. The idea that you have mentioned worked properly for me. May i know are there any resources for understanding OOP from a  very beginner level. If so please let me know, it will help me a lot

Comment: No worries. Keep up the programming and eventually you will understand the concept of OOP. Take a look at this. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear, even though you failed to include the entire message.  Look at the last line in `Student.__init__`:

```
self.lap = self.Laptop()
```

The Laptop instantiation requires three arguments; you supplied none.

You haven't specified how you expect this to work.
If you want a "dummy" Laptop assigned to a new student, then you need to alter `Laptop.__init__` to make a dummy.  If you insist that the Laptop already exist when you instantiate a student, then you need to pass in the existing laptop object -- or perhaps pass in the laptop's arguments.

Comment: if i figured out correctly, you mean to say that i should write it as self.lap = self.Laptop(brand,cpu,ram). I tried this one as well, still it was throwing error

Comment: That is one way, but you have to support that instantiation by passing in the required arguments.  "still it was throwing error" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real reason for `Laptop` to be an attribute of `Student`, or for `Student` to know how to instantiate `Laptop`.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, rollno, laptop):
        self.name = name
        self.rollno = rollno
        self.lap = laptop
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} has roll number {self.rollno}"
    
    def show(self):
        print(self.name + " has " + self.lap.brand + " laptop")
    

class Laptop:
    def __init__(self, brand, cpu, ram):
        self.brand = brand
        self.cpu = cpu
        self.ram = ram
            
    def display(self):
        print(self.brand, self.cpu, self.ram)
        

s1 = Student("Gowtham", 55, Laptop("HP", "i5", "8GB"))
print(s1)
s1.show()
```